# Socket.io not save on Mongoose save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, mongoose, socket.io

I'm creating a simple chat just to study socket.io and how to save data on MongoDb by Mongoose.

After some researching i'm still blocked cause Mongoose doesn't save data.
Here my configuration:

```
// configuration
var app = require('express')();
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

// connect to db
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/chat', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to MongoDb!');
    }
});

// Schema model
var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    msg: String,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, { collection: 'chat' });

// model
var Chat = mongoose.model('Message', chatSchema);

// socket.io
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        var newMsg = new Chat({msg: msg});
        newMsg.save(function(err, product, numberAffected){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                io.emit('chat message', msg);
                // console.log prints everything correctly
                console.log('saved: ' + product + ' - ' + numberAffected);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I don't have any errors in my console,  but if i find some record in my db (by terminal: db.chat.find()) i have and empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chat` is the name of your db and the collection is called `Message`. You should find your records using the terminal like this:

```
use chat
db.Message.find()
```

Comment: thanks! it seems working also with db.chat.find(). Now i have just to find a way to retrieve my data on document ready

Comment: Maybe when the connection is first opened?

io.on('connection', function(socket){

 Chat.find({}, function(err, messages){
  if(!err){
   io.emit('chat message', messages);
  }
 });
        ...
});

Comment: This is another precious suggestion! thank you again!

Comment: also you can type show collections, in the shel to show the collections inside the db

Comment: @Luca Mormile your solution properly update view from database in real time?